# Golang for hackerrank's "Diagonal difference" problem

Tags: go, stdin

need some help, as I'm going crazy here.

So what I have a problem with is reading the first line of stdin input (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem), to get the size of a matrix so I can calculate diagonal sum difference.

If I do the following :

```
var n int
fmt.Scan(&n)
```

I get the output of n being 0, and i want it to be 3.

I also tried like :

```
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
line, _, _ := in.ReadLine()
read_line, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(line))
```

That way I also can only get a 0. 
I'm trying to wrap my head around this, which is precisely the reason I started to learn Go, because I am missing some programming fundamentals, and Go is very opinionated.
Thanks, Help!

EDIT:

Anyways, I just listened to my hunch on there being nothing on stdin and just initialized matrix with the length of the multi-array because I remembered from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd4EPh2tYrk how Go really represents multidimensional arrays in its "system".

Comment: What if you use `fmt.Scanln(&n)`? Btw, `fmt.Scan()` also does that if you run it in a terminal. It returns an error, be so kind to print it. Print errors in all your attempts.

Comment: Hi, thanks, tried your solution also, but it's more about standard Hackerrank deceitfulness, they have nothing on stdin I'm 99% sure, also tried ReadString, nothing was there.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I just listened to my hunch on there being nothing on stdin and just initialized matrix with the length of the multi-array because I remembered from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd4EPh2tYrk how Go really represents multidimensional arrays in its "system", e.g its just flat.